# Properly print entry widget input Python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5

Ok, so here's my problem:

The code below, when called upon by a button, prints *NOTHING*. Why? (Yes, of course I'm typing in input to the entry boxes.)

```
options = Tk()
options.geometry("218x156")
options.iconbitmap('original.ico')
options.title("Options")

Label(options, text = "GitHub Username:").pack()
userName = StringVar()
Entry(options, width = "30", textvariable = userName).pack()

Label(options, text = "GitHub Email:").pack()
userEmail = StringVar()
Entry(options, width = "30", textvariable = userEmail).pack()

Label(options, text = "GitHub Password:").pack()
userPassword = StringVar()
Entry(options, show = "•", width = "30", textvariable = userPassword).pack()

def optionSave():
    print(userName.get())
    print(userEmail.get())
    print(userPassword.get())
    options.destroy()
```

**works, and**

```
def fileOptions():
    options = Tk()
    options.geometry("218x156")
    options.iconbitmap('original.ico')
    options.title("Options")

    Label(options, text = "GitHub Username:").pack()
    userName = StringVar()
    Entry(options, width = "30", textvariable = userName).pack()

    Label(options, text = "GitHub Email:").pack()
    userEmail = StringVar()
    Entry(options, width = "30", textvariable = userEmail).pack()

    Label(options, text = "GitHub Password:").pack()
    userPassword = StringVar()
    Entry(options, show = "•", width = "30", textvariable = userPassword).pack()

    def optionSave():
        print(userName.get())
        print(userEmail.get())
        print(userPassword.get())
        options.destroy()
```

**does not**

*Please note:* the only noticeable difference is that the code on

the bottom is not encased it `def fileOptions():`

The output is blank. As in it prints *zilch* to the console. Is this because it is in a separate Window? If so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now... To answer my own question!

Instead of:

```
userName = StringVar()
Entry(options, width = "30", textvariable = userName).pack()
```

Define the Entry widget like so:

```
userName = StringVar()
userName = Entry(options, width = "30")
userName.pack()
```

Move the `.pack()` down to it's own line as `userName.pack()`
and then print it like so:

```
print(userName.get())
```

For all of the Entry widgets you want.